# Prove that for every real number $x$, if $|x-3|>3$ then $x^2>6x$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that for every real number $x$, if $|x − 3| > 3$ then $x^2 > 6x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400047/prove-that-for-every-real-number-x-if-x-%e2%88%92-3-3-then-x2-6x)

This is exercise $3.5.10$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Prove that for every real number $x$, if $|x-3|>3$ then $x^2>6x$.

Here is my proof:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\Bbb R$. Suppose $|x-3|>3$. Now we consider two different cases.

Case $1.$ Suppose $x-3\geq0$. Ergo $x-3>3$ and so $x>6$. Multiplying both sides of $x>6$ by $x$ we obtain $x^2>6x$.

Case $2.$ Suppose $x-3<0$. Ergo $3-x>3$ and so $x<0$. Since $x<0$, then clearly $x<6$. Multiplying both sides of $x<6$ by $x$ we obtain $x^2>6x$.

Since the above cases are exhaustive, $x^2>6x$. Therefore if $|x-3|>3$ then $x^2>6x$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(|x-3|>3\rightarrow x^2>6)$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

**One other question:** In the above linked-post, there is a clear mistake in the proof:

> Since by one of the cases we have $x^2 > 6x$ then $|x − 3| > 3$
> $\Rightarrow$ $x^2 > 6x$.

But the cases must be exhaustive and from both of them we should reach the conclusion that $x^2>6x$. Is my reasoning correct$?$ If yes, then why no one mentioned it in the comments or the answers to the above post$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your proof looks correct! There is a simpler way: starting with $|x-3|>3$, simply square both sides and simplify.

Comment: @GregMartin I know that but this section of the textbook discusses proofs by splitting into cases and so I became obsessed with giving such a proof.

Comment: You are correct that the proof in the above link is incorrect and no one pointed it out. That's bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
|x-3|>3 & \Rightarrow (x-3)^2>9 \\
 & \Rightarrow x^2-6x+9>9 \\ 
 & \Rightarrow x^2-6x>0 \\
 & \Rightarrow x^2>6x \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: +1, was my first thought, too.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x-3, x>3; -(x-3), x \le 3$$
So $$|x-3|>3 \implies x>6 ~or~ x<0.$$
$$x^2 >6x  \implies x(x-6) >0 \implies x<0 ~or~ x>6.$$
So both the equations are the same.

Also note that $$|x-3|>3 \implies x^2-6x+9>9 \implies x^2>6x,$$
which is more transparent.

Answer (score -1):

For the second case we can say that $x$ is negative,
$x^2$ is positive and $6x$ is negative so $x^2> 6x$